# Magento2: how to fetch product id from local storage in observer

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, local-storage

i want product id from local storage in observer is there any easy way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code in your controller

```
$product_id="<script>document.write(parseInt(Object.keys(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('product_data_storage')))))</script>";
echo 'product id'.$product_id;
```

Comment: it work fine but maybe its not proper method

Comment: yes its not good way to add like that in controller you can use ajax from phtml to get value in controller. by the way can you up vote my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**local storage** it a client-side element and controller is a server-side element. So you have read this variable using js and send to via an ajax request.

```
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
```

Can able to provide local storage data

```
customerData.get('product_data_storage');
```

Comment: can you provide me any reference for that ??

Comment: no, Just have an idea.

Comment: how can i add custom tab in local storage not in under "mage-cache-storage" ?

Comment: this return all cached product mean all those product on which customer visited, but how get current product?